# Einstein-Hilbert Action for Linearized Gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, linearized-theory

Following a derivation for the action in linearized gravity I have reached the point where I have the following expression

$$S = \frac{1}{16 \pi G} \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} R.$$

I know that
$$R = \partial_{\mu}\partial_{\rho}h^{\rho \mu} - \partial_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}h^{\nu}_{\nu} $$
and
$$\sqrt{-g} = 1 + \frac{h^{\nu}_{\nu}}{2} + \frac{(h^{\nu}_{\nu})^{2}}{8} - \frac{h_{\mu \nu}h^{\mu \nu}}{4}.$$

Combining the latter two should result in something that looks like
$$ S = \frac{1}{64 \pi G} \int d^{4}x (h_{\mu \nu} \partial_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha} h^{\mu \nu} + 2 h^{\mu \nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}h_{\nu}^{\nu} - h_{\nu}^{\nu}\partial_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha} h_{\nu}^{\nu} -2h_{\mu \nu}\partial_{\rho}\partial^{\mu}h^{\nu \rho}). $$

However, I cannot follow how this is achieved.

Combining the $\frac{h_{\nu}^{\nu}}{2}$ term with the two terms in R gives the two middle terms in the final Lagrangian density. However, I cannot combine the other terms in a way that produces the first and final term.

Comment: It looks like you're missing an $h$ term ($h^{\mu}_{\mu}$ probably?) from the second term in your final Lagrangian density.

Comment: You've got to expand $R$ to quadratic order in $h$...

Comment: @Buzz This is correct, there should be an $h_{\mu}^{\mu}$ in the second term. I shall try and derive this result again. Thank you.